# Cmake can't find CMAKE_ROOT

Tags: cmake

Cmake throws an error

```
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in

CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache(). Aborting.`
```

Tried everything I could find out there to fix (Creating environment variable to path of installation, reinstalling, installing from source code) but none of these worked, I also tried running it on bash (I usually use zsh) but still no results

Comment: Please update question to specify what system you are using, details on how cmake was installed, details on what was tried.  If you can build cmake from source code I surprised that it did not run correctly.  You don't even need to install it, just run it as /full/path/to/build/bin/cmake and it should work.

Comment: Yeah I think it had a problem like allergy to folders named "build"

Answer (score 7):

Try the following command:

```
hash -r
```

This will cause the shell to forget its cached location of CMake and in doing so resets the environment to allow the newly installed version to take precedence. From `help hash` in bash:

> ```
> hash: hash [-lr] [-p pathname] [-dt] [name ...]
>     Remember or display program locations.
>
>     Determine and remember the full pathname of each command NAME.  If
>     no arguments are given, information about remembered commands is
>     displayed.
>
>     Options:
>       ...
>       -r        forget all remembered locations
> ```

Comment: Can you explain what this has to do with the question?

Comment: Although this solved the problem, it is a bit of magic/cryptic. TIL: `hash -r` forgets all memorized location of commands. I had a different version of cmake before, I removed (via apt remove) and installed (via pip install) a new version of cmake, which caused the problem. `hash -r` erased previous memory of cmake.  I didn't know such a command even existed!

Comment: I edited the answer to better explain the solution and cast an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, my error was similar:

```
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/home/user/.local/share/cmake-3.25
cmake version 3.25.0-rc1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

I had installed cmake on Ubuntu using `apt`. However, the system was still looking for the cmake installation in my home directory.

I simply did a link to the system directory:

```
$ ln -s /usr/share/cmake-3.25 ~/.local/share/
```

Problem solved!

```
$ cmake --version                            
cmake version 3.25.0-rc1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Answer (score -2):

I had to re-install my cmake to correct this same error.

```
sudo apt-get remove cmake cmake-data
sudo -E add-apt-repository -y ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
sudo -E apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

Comment: **This suggestion is irresponsible.** Kitware provides an official repository for Debian and Ubuntu. One should never use a PPA under these circumstances. See here: https://apt.kitware.com/

Comment: Not to mention that repo hasn't been updated in years and tops out at CMake 3.5. Meanwhile, the current release is 3.22 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS packages 3.16.

Comment: @starball - if I did, it was two years ago. I honestly don't remember.