Cmake on Cygwin: CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT
I installed Cmake 3.28.3 using Cygwin installer.
However, cmake produces CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!:
$ /bin/cmake --version
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/share/cmake-3.28.3
cmake version 3.28.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

I installed Cmake 3.25.3 using Cygwin installer.
However, cmake produces CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!:
$ /bin/cmake --version
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/share/cmake-3.25.3
cmake version 3.25.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

System information:
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19045 xxx 3.5.3-1.x86_64 2024-04-03 17:25 UTC x86_64 Cygwin

I've already tried to relaunch Cygwin and to reboot the OS. No effect.
Any ideas why this happen and how to fix?

During re-installation progress log I found that files are installed into /usr/share/cmake-3.28.3 while Cmake is looking for /share/cmake-3.28.3.
So, I created directory /share and symbolic link:
$ mkdir /share
$ ln -s /usr/share/cmake-3.28.3 /share/cmake-3.28.3

I don't know whether this is a bug in the installer or in Cmake.
See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76741707/1778275.
